# Wordpress URL Issues for my custom template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have developed a wordpress template with woocommerce support . 
but in all pages it shows an extra code like this after url :

http://www.*****.com/?v=e6bebe6e54a9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce will append this if you have the default customer location in settings to be `Geolocate (with page caching support)`. If you don't want this, simply change the setting.

You can find this in **WooCommerce >> Settings >> General**

[image: ?v= number after url woocommerce]