# Woocommerce adding version(?) GET Parameters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

since a few days my wordpress url looks sth. like this

```
www.mypage.com/?v=180c0811311f
```

After deactivating all plugins and activating one another I know that this param comes from woocommerce, but what does it do? And how can i get rid of it?

All help is highly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments in the [source code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cache-helper.php#L47) this variable is used by the WooCommerce geolocation functionality.

```
/**
 * When using geolocation via ajax, to bust cache, redirect if the location hash does not equal the querystring.
 *
 * This prevents caching of the wrong data for this request.
 */
```

This functionality is only active if the option value for `woocommerce_default_customer_address` is `geolocation_ajax`, so changing it to something else will prevent the `v=` from being appended.

```php
if ( 'geolocation_ajax' === get_option( 'woocommerce_default_customer_address' ) && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's duplication for [Wordpress URL Issues for my custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862887/wordpress-url-issues-for-my-custom-template) you just need to change **Default customer address** in Woocommerce settings to other than *Geolocate (with page caching support)*