# Wordpress Woocommerce Redirect Argument

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When I enable my site automatically show argument `?v=` like this

```
com / ?v=d71bdd22c8bb
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: your question need more clarifications.

Comment: here is my site: http://www.craft-shopping.com When we visit it it automatically add argument to url Named ?v but when we disable woo commerce then Fine

Comment: i want to Remove ?v Argument From URL ....

Comment: i have not seen any option to edit ?v argument from backend @Firefog

Comment: I have update my answer with fix . hope it will help you.

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862887/wordpress-url-issues-for-my-custom-template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String to all urls ?v=XXXXXXXXXXXX. That URL is coming from standard base address setting in Woocommerce. When you choose geolocation with caching support for page, it will add that ?v=xxxx string because it's capturing the visitors base address

TO fix it goto **woocommerce->settings->Default Customer Address** change it to Shop base address

[image]

[More Info ->](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/making-geolocation-static-cache-friendly-in-2-4/)