# Enabling WooCommerce change my Website links

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have a problem. I have a website they call for example

```html
www.test.com
```

Now If I install WooCommerce, that changes my basic link to:

```html
www.test.com/?v=19facac09d7d
```

I realy dont know why.

How can I change this in WooCommerce?

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862887/wordpress-url-issues-for-my-custom-template

Answer (score 2):

Thats comes from the geolocation setting. https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7939

Comment: can i disabled it?

Comment: or hide it in the link?

Comment: Yes. In WooCommerce > Settings > General https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

You have to change the settings in the woocommerce -> general settings ->Default Customer Address.

To Shop base address.