# WordPress generates a weird address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website and I notice that my URL is not correct, it generates a weird text `?v=2a4b9e2e4254` for example `http://my-domain/?v=2a4b9e2e4254`, and this text is appears in every page and post, e.g. `http://my-domain/contact/?v=2a4b9e2e4254`

Any ideas on how can I fix this? I tried everything on phpMyadmin on wp-config with no result.

Comment: What plugins are you using? Where are you hosting?

Comment: Hi Chris, I use WooCommerce, some plugins from YITH and my host is freehostia. It is not host issue I saw that I have the same problem also in my localhost only on this site

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862887/wordpress-url-issues-for-my-custom-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v` argument is [added by WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204937/why-v-hash-is-added-to-my-urls) if [geolocation with page caching support is enabled](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/):

> **Geolocate with page caching support** is the same as above, but does the geolocation via Ajax. You may notice your website URLs have a *?v=xxxxx* appended to them. This is normal to prevent static caching of prices.

As long as you don't need that feature you should be able to disable it in your WooCommerce configuration.